# Monotone convergence for monotone functions in BV

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, bounded-variation

For $n \geq 1$ let $f, f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be monotone nonincreasing functions. Suppose that $f_n \nearrow f$ pointwise monotonically as $n \to \infty$.

Is then $\mathrm{TV}(f - f_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\mathrm{TV}$ is the total variation?

Note that assuming $f_n$ to be merely of bounded variation is not enough: If $f_n$ is the negative of the indicator function of $(0, 1/n)$ then $f_n \nearrow 0$ pointwise monotonically, but $\mathrm{TV}(f_n) = 2$ for each $n$.

If the answer is "yes", I would appreciate a proof without the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem.

**Edit**. $f := 1_{[0, 1)}$ and $f_n := 1_{[0, 1 - 1/n)}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another counterexample, with **uniform** convergence $f_n\nearrow f$.

Turn the Cantor staircase upside down. Take a sequence of smooth decreasing functions $f_n$ converging to it monotonically. (These can be obtained by approximating $f-2^{-n}$ within $4^{-n}$ by convolution with a smooth mollifier.).

Since $f$ is constant on each component of the complement of the Cantor set $C$, we have 
$$
TV(f-f_n) \ge \int_{[0,1]\setminus C}|f_n'| = \int_{[0,1] }|f_n'| =1
$$
(Recall $C$ has zero measure.)